# Create a custom Link to a File-Field in Twig

Tags: theming, 8, files

I'm trying to customize a download-link for a file-field in my entity. 
In a similar setup, i was able to customize a link-field in the following way:

```
<a href="{{ node.field_publication_link.uri }}"> Link </a>
```

So, for the file-field, i tried something similar:

```
<a href="{{ node.field_publication_file.0.uri }}"> Download </a>
```

However, there is no such thing as a `uri` field available. I have a hard time figuring out which fields actually are available for me to use in the template. I found `kint` to be way too noisy, i had to restrict memory consumption and still have no clue which fields are usable.

Alternatively, i tried to create a custom template for the specific file field, called `field--field-publication-file.html.twig`. The debug info tells me that it is used for rendering. 
I had a look at the field that my theme (bootstrap) normally uses and tried to mimick its behavior. Specifically, i wanted to use the field `link`, which is also used in the bootstrap version. However, this field is always empty when using my version.

What more could i try?

Answer (score 2):

After more research, i found the answer by accident on [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates) page. One can refer to the link by using:

```
<a href="{{ file_url (node.field_publication_file.entity.uri.value) }}"> 
  Download
</a>
```

The fields that were defined in the bootstrap theme don't seem to be accessible in a sub-theme of bootstrap. I'm sure I could have written a custom preprocessor to do the same thing, but this solution works for me and I don't have to write PHP code.

Comment: You can also use `node.field_publication_file.entity.url()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either way, using the file_url available on twig template or you can use `file_create_url($file_uri);` in the preprocessor, so that your template can easily consume the processed output.

Code at preprocess layer, assuming node as the host entity.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node($node) {
   if (!$node->your_file_field_machine_name->isEmpty()) {
     $file_entities = $node->get('your_file_field_machine_name')->referencedEntities();
     if(count($file_entities)) {
        foreach($file_entities as $file_entity) {
            $variables['file_renderable'][] = file_create_url($file_entity->getFileUri());
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Other way is what you mentioned, use `file_url` at your twig template.

```
<a href="{{ file_url (node.field_publication_file.entity.uri.value) }}"> 
  Download
</a>
```